# How to "create table as (select * from)"

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to use data from the existing table and create a new table using it. I am using local database (.mdf) file to store my data.

I am not able to execute the following line:

```
SqlCommand com = 
           new SqlCommand("create table newinfo as (select * from oldinfo)", connection);
```

Is there any alternative way to create a table in C# from the data selected from another table.

Comment: You could use SELECT * INTO newinfo from oldinfo

Comment: This a question regarding SQL. Not C#.

Comment: You aren't able? why? do you get an error? Regardless, **NEVER** use `SELECT *`. If this is Oracle this might work. Not if its SQL Server. If you actually tag with the database type we might be able to help.

Comment: what is the error that it returns? Maybe the login you are using on your application does not have the right to create a table on your db.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `SELECT INTO`:

```
SELECT * INTO YourNewTable FROM YourOldTable
```

See more here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd401720.aspx

Answer (score 1):

To create a table from a select statement you use the following syntax

```
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3
INTO NewTable
FROM ExistingTable
```